# Why do browsers use white text on a blue background for highlighted areas?

Tags: color-scheme, browser, highlight

I just checked in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, on Windows, and all three default to blue background and white text when the user highlights some area, perhaps for a `search google for`, `copy` or `inspect element` operation.

What is the reason for this choice? I'm looking for direct info from a browser vendor or strong evidence from elsewhere that supports this choice, rather than opinion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an OS-level thing--not a browser implementation.

Comment: @DA01 ok, I don't think that effects the ux element of the question

Comment: Probably not. I don't know the answer, but have a strong hunch it is "because someone on the OS UI team decided to make it that way"

Comment: If you don't like it, there's a CSS pseudo-element [::selection], which allows you to [change the color of selected text highlight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection).

Comment: just checked my Mac at work and it's a lighter blue with dark grey

Comment: @Rob that isn't strictly true, the browsers have a default colour scheme for highlighting which is taken from the operating system, in my blue and white for windows, though it varies for Macs - the dev can over-ride this, but I was wondering if there was any rationale behind the current choices - i.e. I have been told (but not corroborated) that white text on a blue background is useful for types of dyslexia

Comment: I doubt dyslexia was part of the criteria. After all, you're highlighting something typically *after* you've already read it. While there may have been very specific rationale, keep in mind that just as often, it's just a pure subjective aesthetic decision made by someone back in the day that we've kept using out of habit.

Comment: @DA01 - true, however, it's not difficult to select something you'd like to read - I've done it many times on sites with poor text to background contrast.

Answer (score 2):

This is also just an opinion but it is based on some facts.

Just like @DA01 has a hunch on question comments, most probable answer is "because someone on the OS UI team decided to make it that way". But why such a choice was made? The same can be asked about links, why they are blue.

I have always explained the reason for these color choises to be the limitations of the hardware. Some might remember that back in the day monitors (graphic cards) had a little less colors on their disposal.

In two-tone you probably use inverted colors to show the selection. With 16 colours you use something else (other than black when text is black or white when text is white), thou the palette is limited. So someone decided on blue because it seemed more neutral than red or green.

Comment: No idea if it's true, but certainly a plausible theory!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a random choice, Red and green are the colours most affected by colour-vision deficiency.  Almost no one has a blue deficiency. 
And (but I doubt that's that) we use Blue because of science : http://www.fastcompany.com/3009317/why-is-facebook-blue-the-science-behind-colors-in-marketing

Comment: But it's a highlight color. All that is important is that it's different than the non-highlighted text. As such, colorblindness isn't an issue in this context.